# UIKit: Buttons aren't appearing

Tags: html, css, getuikit

So far so good i'm not overriding anything, But the buttons aren't appearing normally:

this is a test project and has nothing in it:

My HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="dahv backend">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'> 

    <title>dahv backend</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/cache_buster.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/handling.js"></script>      

    <!-- UIkit CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" />

</head>


<body>
    <br>
<br> 
   <div class="uk-button-group">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default"></button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default"></button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default"></button>
</div>


     <!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Also my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ED4C67;
}
```

Result:

[Browser Screenshot 31 Dec, 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMWAL.png)

Is there a problem with UIKit or my browser (safari)?

Comment: Did you try adding text in the buttons?

Comment: @SagiRika oh god how dumb can i be sometimes, thank you sir

Comment: Sometimes we always go to the complicated solutions and miss the simple ones. Happy to help :)